# Javascript addEventListener somehow not working with querySelector in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, addeventlistener, queryselector

I'm working on Laravel 5.8 and i want to add simple javascript inside my project. It works fine without the query selector :

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    console.log(1);
  });
```

But somehow the js doesn't work when I insert a querySelector to it.

```
document.querySelector('.col-md-8.menus').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    console.log(1);
  });
```

I tested it manually on my browser console and the event fires properly. I've made sure there are no other classes in other blade templates using that class name. My guess is it probably has something to do with Laravel since I also tested it in a dummy html and it's working properly there.

The `app.blade` is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    @include('include.head')
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app" style="min-height:1500px">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark shadow-sm" >
          @include('include.navbar')
      </nav>

      <!--<main class="py-4">-->
          <div class="container" > 
          @yield('content')
          </div>
      <!--</main> -->
  </div>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector('.col-md-8.menus').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    console.log(1);
  });

  [...document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tabs a.pr-5.py-3')].forEach(link => link.innerHTML = link.innerHTML.replace('_', ' '));
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[name="kategori"] option')].forEach(option => option.innerHTML = option.innerHTML.replace('_', ' '));

</script>

<footer class="row">
    @include('include.footer')
</footer>
</html>
```

and the blade where the selector referenced to (go to `<!--Menu List-->` comment):

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container" style="padding:0px">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background-image:url({{asset('bg.jpg')}})">
        <div class="container my-4">
            <h1 class="display-4">Selamat Datang di Restoran Acin</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="container pt-4" align=center>
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
    </div>  <div class="container my-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <h5 class="card-header">
                            Status
                        </h5>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p>Meja Kosong : </p> 
                        <p>Meja Penuh : </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Menu List -->
            <div class="col-md-8 menus">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3 pt-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">Nama : Nasi Goreng</div>
                            <div class="card-body">Harga :  12000</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 pt-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">Nama : Nasi Goreng</div>
                            <div class="card-body">Harga :  12000</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 pt-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">Nama : Nasi Goreng</div>
                            <div class="card-body">Harga :  12000</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 pt-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">Nama : Nasi Goreng</div>
                            <div class="card-body">Harga :  12000</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Order List -->
            <div class="col-md-4 order">
                <div class="card mt-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="d-flex order">
                            <span class="nama-order">Nasi Goreng</span>
                            <span class="harga-order">15000</span>
                            <span class="delete-makanan"><button class="btn btn-primary"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mt-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="d-flex order">
                            <span>Nasi Goreng</span>
                            <span>15000</span>
                            <span class="delete-makanan"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Hapus</button></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="order-template">
            <div class="card mt-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="d-flex order">
                        <span>Nasi Goreng</span>
                        <span>15000</span>
                        <span class="delete-makanan"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Hapus</button></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <contoh-component></contoh-component> <!-- testing vue component-->
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if you place this inside of a window.onload? E.g.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    document.querySelector('.col-md-8.menus').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        // ...
    });
};
```

The reason why this may be happening is because the DOM hasn't been loaded yet so `document.querySelector('.col-md-8.menus')` isn't finding anything.

Onload Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: Yeah apprently the DOM doesn't load completely which I didn't knew about. Your solution has fixed it. Thanks a lot

Comment: This was the solution for me. So strange because the inspector showed the form element but the event listenering still didn't work without this solution.